# Using v-if with slice on a string literal

Tags: vue.js

I want to toggle whether a card is rendered in my vue app.
I am using v-if on v-card
Code:

```
myString == "MONEY
<v-card v-if="`${myString.slice(4,5)}` == "EY".
```

I get the error that .slice is not a function...I know it works for

```
`${myString.length}`== 5
```

Comment: here `myString == "MONEY` you're doing a comparison or an assignment?

Comment: I'm using an assignment - basically I would like to know how to use string literals when using v-if in vue.js.

Comment: it should be `myString = "MONEY"` please share your script

Answer (score 0):

Slice is zero based so you may want to try.

```
myString.slice(3,5)
```

or

```
myString.slice(3)
```

Comment: Still get the error - can you show an example of the following scenario: myString = "REG" and <v-card v-if="`${myString.slice(1,2)}` == "E" .... this gives the error . it seems that vue sees this as a function.